# Convert GLE2S0 shader to GLES30 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a code that based on GLES20, Now when I tried to work with GLES30 the code doesn't work.

I already tried to do so using [THIS](http://www.shaderific.com/blog/2014/3/13/tutorial-how-to-update-a-shader-for-opengl-es-30) guide, but it still didn't work.

I believe that maybe I missed something here.

This is the "Shaders" code based on GLES20:

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
    "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
    "    vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
    "}\n";

private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
    "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
    "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "    vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
    "    gl_FragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
    "    gl_FragColor.g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
    "    gl_FragColor.b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
    "}\n";
```

In this code, I've got a frame from recorded video and convert every RPB channel to grayscale.

Can someone help me to convert it using GLES30 please?

**Update 1:**

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "#version 300 es\n"+
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
        "in  vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "in  vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "out vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "    vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
        "}\n";

private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "#version 300 es\n"+
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
        "out vec3 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

**Update 2:**

The code bellow works but still I've got only zeros in the output buffer

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
        "#version 300 es\n"+
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
        "in  vec4 aPosition;\n" +
        "in  vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
        "out vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
        "    vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
        "}\n";

private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "#version 300 es\n"+
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
        "in vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
        "out vec4 fragColor ;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    vec4 tc = texture(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "    fragColor .r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    fragColor .g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    fragColor .b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

Comment: What didn't work? Please post your updated code.

Comment: OK I'll update it

Comment: `vTextureCoord` is a vertex shader output; thus it should be an input variable in the fragment shader.

Comment: Doesn't work- I've got only zeroes

Comment: What does the log say? There must be some kind of error.

Comment: You are right, I've got "glDrawArrays: glError 1282" for every frame

Comment: I meant the log from `glGetProgram/ShaderInfoLog` after compiling and linking the shaders.

Comment: OK, This is the error I've got from glGetShaderInfoLog : 0:1: Warning: GL_OES_EGL_image_external is deprecated in ESSL 3 and later versions. Use GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 instead
0:7: L0002: No matching function for call to 'textureCube'
0:8: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_FragColor'
0:9: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_FragColor'
0:10: L0002: Undeclared variable 'gl_FragColor'

Comment: I've fixed the first error. but I don't understand why "texture2D","texture2d" and "textureCube" doesn't found. 
I tried all of them but it doesn't work

Comment: Use `texture()` - as was explained in the guide you linked to.

Comment: I tried this and there is no errors now. But still I've got only zeroes.

Comment: One more thing, I saw that in order to read the data from the Fragcolor I've used the old version on the GLES, but even after change it to this :  GLES30.glReadPixels(startX, startY, frameWidth, frameHeight, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                           mPixelBuf); I'm still getting zeroes

Comment: I'll update the code that works for me. the only thing that I don't understand. is if gl_Fragcolor is not an known input, how opengl know what is the new input the I defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123430/discussion-between-user2235615-and-pleluron).

Comment: You need to use samplerExternalOES to sample sTexture